# I can't store integers inside an array

Tags: c, arrays

**This is an activity given by my instructor.**

*Create a program that accepts numeric input from the user. If the user enters an even number, store it to an array for even numbers. If the user enters an odd number, store it to another array for odd numbers. Input terminates if the user entered 10 numbers already. Display the size of each array and their elements.*

*Example:*

Input: `5, 6, 12, 10, 0, 3, 4, 100, -1, 7`

Even numbers `(6): 6 12 10 0 4 100`

Odd numbers `(4): 5 3 -1 7`

and this is the code I've come up with.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sort(int);

int main(){
    int input, count;

    for(count=0;count!=10;count++){
        printf("Enter 10 digits: ");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        sort(input);
        }

    printf("%d", input);

    return 0;
    }

int sort(int inp){
    int odd[10];
    int even[10];

    if(inp%2==0){
        odd[]=inp;
        }

    else
        even[]=inp;

    return 0;
    }
```

Please help me on how to store the numbers into two separate arrays. Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `int odd[10]; int even[10];` are local to `sort()`. don't do that.

Comment: note that if a (number mod 2) == 0 then it is even not odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code. It's self-explaining.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM 10

int main()
{
    int input, i;
    int oddcounter = 0, evencounter =0;
    int oddarr[NUM];
    int evenarr[NUM];

    printf("Enter 10 integers\n");  

    for (i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        if ( scanf("%d", &input) == 1 )
        {
            if ((input % 2) == 0)
            {
                evenarr[evencounter++]  = input;
            }
            else
            {
                oddarr[oddcounter++] = input;
            }
        }

    }
    printf("Number of elem in oddarray : %d, evenarray : %d\n\n", oddcounter, evencounter);

    printf("Odd elements are :");
    for (i = 0; i < oddcounter ; i++) printf("%d\t", oddarr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Even elements are :");
    for (i = 0; i < evencounter; i++) printf("%d\t", evenarr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This one worked. Thanks! I'll be studying your code in the mean time and try to understand it.

Comment: what does this line mean?

if ( scanf("%d", &input) == 1 ){

Comment: @FrancisDoy that is a check for the success of `scanf()`. read the man page of `scanf()` for more information. :-)

Comment: can you help me write a line to list all the 10 inputted numbers?

Comment: @FrancisDoy if the order of input is not required to maintain,  `printf("Number of elem in oddarray : %d, evenarray : %d\n\n", oddcounter, evencounter);  for (i = 0; i < oddcounter ; i++) printf("%d\t", oddarr[i]);  for (i = 0; i < evencounter; i++) printf("%d\t", evenarr[i]);   printf("\n");` will print all numbers.

Comment: @FrancisDoy otherwise, if you want to print all the numbers in the same order as they were given input, you've to maintain a third array.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Sourav's comment which indicates that you shouldn't have the `int[]` arrays be local to `sort`, this syntax isn't correct for assigning to arrays in C:

```
odd[]=inp;
```

On my compiler, it generates the following error:

```
24:9: error: expected expression
    odd[]=inp;
```

To store to `odd`, you need to indicate the index at which you'd like to store, for example:

```
odd[1]=inp;
```

which also means you'll need to keep track the latest index you wrote to for each array!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the compiler which index of the array you are storing your data to.  In `sort`:

```
if(inp%2==0){
    odd[]=inp;
}

else
    even[]=inp;

return 0;
}
```

Should look something like:

```
if(inp%2==0){
    odd[endofoddindex]=inp;
    }

else
    even[endofevenindex]=inp;

return 0;
}
```

That said, you won't get much use out of the arrays being local variables, since they are deallocated on each call.  Your best bet is to declare the arrays in `main` and pass them in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either have your arrays as globals or pass them into your sort function. Where they are they currently they get recreated every time the sort function is called and are inaccessible to the rest of your program.
You will also need to keep track of the max number of ints in each array and the current number.

Your test in sort would be something like this:

```
if( inp % 2 == 0)
{
   //TODO check that currentEvenCount < maxEvenCount
   even[ currentEvenCount ] = inp;
   currentEvenCount++
}
else
{
   //TODO check that currentOddCount < maxOddCount
   odd[ currentOddCount ] = inp;
   currentOddCount++;
}
```

To declare your arrays as globals just move the declaration outside of any function above anywhere they are referenced

```
int even[10];
int odd[10];

int main() ...
```

To pass them as parameters to sort function you could declare sort like this:

```
sort( int inp, int even[], int maxEvenCount, int* currentEvenCount, int odd[]. int maxOddCount, int* currentOddCount)
{
    ...
    if( inp % 2 == 0)
    {
      //TODO check that currentEvenCount < maxEvenCount
      even[ *currentEvenCount ] = inp;
      (*currentEvenCount)++
    }

}
```

The * in front of currentEventCount is dereferencing the pointer and getting/setting the actual value pointed to.

You would then call sort like so:

```
int main()
{
   int evenArray[10];
   int oddArray[10];

  int currentEvenCount = 0;
  int currentOddCount = 0;


   ...
   sort( input, evenArray, 10, &currentEvenCount, oddArray, 10, &currentOddCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this program will solve you issue. Here is the working code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sort(int[]);

int main(){
    int input[10], count;

    printf("Enter 10 digits: ");

    for(count=0;count<10;count++){
        scanf("%d", &input[count]);
    }
    sort(input);
    return 0;
}

int sort(int inp[]){
    int odd[10];
    int even[10];
    int oddCount=0, evenCount=0;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
        if(inp[i]%2==0){
           even[evenCount]=inp[i];
           evenCount++;
        }
        else
        {
           odd[oddCount]=inp[i];
           oddCount++;
         }
     }
     printf("ODD COUNT is %d \n", oddCount);
     for(i=0; i<oddCount;i++)
     {
         printf("ODD VALUE %d \n", odd[i]);
     }
     printf("EVEN COUNT is %d \n", evenCount);
     for(i=0; i<evenCount;i++)
     {
         printf("EVEN VALUE %d \n", even[i]);
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You forgot to actually index by `oddCount` and `evenCount`, but I like this solution.

Comment: May I know who down vote the solution. Please explain me the reason for it.

Comment: Your program has several mistakes in it. Run it. You'll see what's wrong in it

Comment: @CoolGuy :: Thanks for your comment. Now i made it to work as expected.

Comment: Nope. Did you run it? Does `ODD VALUE` and `EVEN VALUE` print?

Comment: @CoolGuy :: Sorry Editing mistake. Now i corrected that.

Comment: Why not use `i` itself instead of many variables like `k` and `j`? And please add a `\n` in the end of the `printf` so that the output looks clean.

Comment: @CoolGuy:: Thanks for your valuable time and feedback. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any sense to define the arrays as local variables of function sort because each time the function is called the arrays are created anew.

The program could look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

enum Type { Even, Odd };

enum Type sort( int x )
{
    return x % 2 == 0 ? Even : Odd;
}

int main( void )
{
    int odd[N];
    int even[N];
    int odd_count = 0;
    int even_count = 0;

    int i;

    printf( "Enter %d numbers: ", N );

    for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        int num;
        scanf( "%d", &num );

        switch ( sort( num ) )
        {
        case Even:
            even[even_count++] = num;
            break;
        case Odd:
            odd[odd_count++] = num;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf( "Even numbers (%d):", even_count );
    for ( i = 0; i < even_count; i++ ) printf( " %d", even[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    printf( "Odd numbers (%d):", odd_count );
    for ( i = 0; i < odd_count; i++ ) printf( " %d", odd[i] );
    printf( "\n" );


    return 0;
}
```

If to enter

```
5  6 12 10 0 3 4 100 -1 7
```

then the output will be

```
Even numbers (6): 6 12 10 0 4 100
Odd numbers (4): 5 3 -1 7
```

Simply copy, paste and investigate the program.:)

Answer (score 0):

Your `even` and `odd` arrays are both local. This means that they exist as long as the function exists. So you won't be retrieve the data you have stored(You also don't store it correctly).

So you need both the arrays in `main` and also two other variables for using as the index of both the array(`i` and `j` in the below program). The modified program is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sort(int);

int main(){
    int input, count,i=0,j=0; //i and j to be used as array indices
    int odd[10];
    int even[10]; //arrays in main

    for(count=0;count!=10;count++){
        printf("Enter 10 digits: ");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        if(sort(input)) //if odd number was found
            odd[i++]=input;
        else //even number found
            even[j++]=input;
        }

    printf("%d", input);
    //print even and odd arrays here
    return 0;
    }

int sort(int inp){
    if(inp%2==0)
        return 0; //if number is even,return 0

    return 1; //else return 1
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Your variable `input` is just an `int`, it's not an array. You need two arrays:

```
int even[10], odd[10];
```

Then you need to keep track of the number of numbers you've read so far, and for each number check which array to store it in.

I don't see a need to do sorting, so not sure why you have a function called `sort()`.

It should just be something like:

```
int even[10], odd[10];
int oddindex = 0, evenindex = 0;
while(scanf(" %d", &x) == 1)
{
  if(x % 2 == 0)
    even[evenindex++] = x;
  else
    odd[oddindex++] = x;
  if((evenindex + oddindex) >= 10)
    break;
}
/* Loop here to print numbers. */
```

Comment: but OP asks to store in seperate arrays!! and if not stored, how to display the elements?

Comment: again, why `100` when the total imput is limited to `10`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh No particular reason, I guess. I changed it again. This answer really rocks! :)

Answer (score -2):

An answer suitable for an assignment question:

```
int main()
{
    int i,c,o[10],e[10];int oc=0;int ec=0;int*pc;for(c=0;c<10;c++){scanf("%d",&i);pc=(i&1)?&o[oc++]:&e[ec++];*pc=i;}
    // Now print out the values as requested in oc, o, ec and e.
}
```

Comment: I think he is a beginner, maybe you could put your answer on multiple lines :)

Comment: @NicolasCharvozKurzawa I know, it's also an assignment question and SO isn't supposed to be used for doing poeple's homework.  I couldn't resist the obfuscated solution.  :-P